# Storyboard scene shows up black when associated with a new class

Tags: iphone, class, xcode-storyboard

I am creating an app and am using storyboards but there is one scene that displays fine when I have just created the interface, but when I assign a new class to the scene it shows up black with just the navigation bar visible. The view is embedded in a UINavigationController and I am trying to display it using a segue that is connected to the UINavigationController.

I have tried assigning it to a blank UIViewController subclass, setting it as the initial view controller, setting the UINavigationController as the initial view controller, trying to display the view using a button rather than programatically and changing all the different settings for the view, and nothing makes any difference. Thanks in advance to anyone who has any clue as to why this is happening!

Comment: have you done a clean and build on your project?

Comment: Yes, I've cleaned the build folder, uninstalled and reinstalled the app and also tried it on the simulator. If I use an existing class it shows up fine, it's only new classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by commenting out the 'load view' method.